# Linux file copy from mounted NAS to remote server using scp

Tags: linux, file, scp, nas

file1 is on the NAS mounted ServerA.

ServerA
/mntnas/file1

ServerB
/dest

If doing:
user@ServerA> scp /mntnas/file1 user@ServerB:/dest

will the file1 transfer go through ServerA or directly from NAS to ServerB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are logged in as `user` on `ServerA`, therefore scp will start an ssh session *from* `ServerA` to `ServerB` to copy the file.

Because `scp` doesnt know anything about networked storage it will let the filesystem handle giving it the bytes that the file is made up of, so your file will be transferred from

```
            NAS -> ServerA -(ssh tunnel)-> ServerB
```